# How to delete data inside the list using bootstrap modal?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I just want to delete the data inside the table using bootstrap modal, but it seems so hard to find the right way how to do this, here's my sample code. Inside my modal I have an href code that use to delete the data
, it is working outside the modal. I just want to know any solution make this working. thanks.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var student = [{
  name: 'Andrew'
}, {
  name: 'Butler'
}, {
  name: 'Cameron'
}, {
  name: 'Delo'
}, {
  name: 'Emman'
}, {
  name: 'Ferbs'
}];

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
  return function(input, start) {
    if (input) {
      start = +start; //parse to int
      return input.slice(start);
    }
    return [];
  }
});

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.list = student;
  $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
  $scope.entryLimit = 10; //max no of items to display in a page
  $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter
  $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;

  $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
  };

  $scope.filter = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
    }, 10);
  };


  $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
  };



});

app.filter('startsWithA', function() {
  return function(items, letter) {
    console.log(items, letter)
    var filtered = [];
    var letterMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (letterMatch.test(item.name.substring(0, 1))) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }
    console.log(filtered);
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="titleHead"><center>Student List</center></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="option-panel">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
          <form class="navbar-form">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-click="filter()" placeholder="Search student" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav navbar-default">
        <div class="tab-panel">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li class="active" name="active"><a ng-click="letter = '[AB]'">A-B</a> 
              </li>
              <li class="active" name="active"><a ng-click="letter = '[CD]'">C-D</a> 
              </li>
              <li class="active" name="active"><a ng-click="letter = '[EF]'">E-F</a> 
              </li>


            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="no-more-tables">
        <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-condensed cf" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
          <thead class="cf">
            <tr>

              <th>
                <center>Name&nbsp;
                  <a ng-click="sort_by('first_name');"></a>
                </center>
              </th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody color="#">
            <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search |orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit |startsWithA:letter |limitTo:entryLimit ">
              <td data-title="Name" class="text-center">{{data.name}}      <a type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" style="width: 40%;" href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Delete</a>
 </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <center>
              <h4>No results found</h4>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
          <center>
            <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>
          </center>
        </div>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Student</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Do you want to delete this student?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/students/edit/studentform/{{data.id}}" >Yes</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest using [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), or similar, for removing a record. Also, You'll notice that I made a change to the way your controller was organized by using the controller as syntax, and assigning everything to the controller, and not to the scope. That way you can pass on the controllers scope to directives and such more easily.

The idea is that you preserve an ID of the selected item, so that you can use it later on when you trigger the server delete action.
This can be done in many different ways, this is just one of the ways.

Hope this helps.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    var student = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Andrew'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Butler'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Cameron'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Delo'
    }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Emman'
    }, {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Ferbs'
    }];

    app.filter('startFrom', function() {
        return function(input, start) {
            if (input) {
                start = +start; //parse to int
                return input.slice(start);
            }
            return [];
        }
    });

    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($http, $timeout) {

        var vm = this,
            itemId = null;

        /**
         * Store a selected item's ID
         * @param id
         */
        vm.getItemId = function (id) {
            itemId = id;
        };

        /**
         * Remove the selected item from the list
         */
        vm.deleteItemFunction = function () {
            console.log('remove', itemId);

            // And then something like this
            $http.delete('/students/edit/studentform/' + itemId).success(function () {
                console.log('successfully removed');
            });
        };



        
        
        
        

        vm.list = student;
        vm.currentPage = 1; //current page
        vm.entryLimit = 10; //max no of items to display in a page
        vm.filteredItems = vm.list.length; //Initially for no filter
        vm.totalItems = vm.list.length;

        vm.setPage = function(pageNo) {
            vm.currentPage = pageNo;
        };

        vm.filter = function() {
            $timeout(function() {
                vm.filteredItems = vm.filtered.length;
            }, 10);
        };


        vm.sort_by = function(predicate) {
            vm.predicate = predicate;
            vm.reverse = !vm.reverse;
        };
    });

    app.filter('startsWithA', function() {
        return function(items, letter) {
            console.log(items, letter)
            var filtered = [];
            var letterMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                var item = items[i];
                if (letterMatch.test(item.name.substring(0, 1))) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                }
            }
            console.log(filtered);
            return filtered;
        };
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="customersCtrl as customer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 id="titleHead"><center>Student List</center></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="option-panel">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
                    <form class="navbar-form">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-click="customer.filter()" placeholder="Search student" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav navbar-default">
                <div class="tab-panel">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active" name="active"><a ng-click="letter = '[AB]'">A-B</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active" name="active"><a ng-click="letter = '[CD]'">C-D</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="active" name="active"><a ng-click="letter = '[EF]'">E-F</a>
                            </li>


                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="no-more-tables">
                <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-condensed cf" ng-show="customer.filteredItems > 0">
                    <thead class="cf">
                    <tr>

                        <th>
                            <center>Name&nbsp;
                                <a ng-click="customer.sort_by('first_name');"></a>
                            </center>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody color="#">
                    <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (customer.list | filter:search |orderBy : customer.predicate : customer.reverse) | startFrom:(customer.currentPage-1)* customer.entryLimit |startsWithA:letter |limitTo: customer.entryLimit ">
                        <td data-title="Name" class="text-center">
                            {{data.name}}      
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" style="width: 40%;" href="#" ng-click="customer.getItemId(data.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="customer.filteredItems == 0">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <center>
                            <h4>No results found</h4>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="customer.filteredItems > 0">
                    <center>
                        <div pagination="" page="customer.currentPage" on-select-page="customer.setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="customer.filteredItems" items-per-page="customer.entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>
                    </center>
                </div>

                <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Student</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Do you want to delete this student?</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="customer.deleteItemFunction()">Yes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, how are you handling the routes? Are you using the ngRouter, or are you handling them server side?